# symfony2: how to write the methods for a many to many relationship?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created these two models below (Author and Book) associated through a many to many relation. Then I have generated the crud methods.

The problem: when I try to create or save an author it doesn't save the books.

```
namespace Prueba\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="author")
 */
class Author
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */ 
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="authors")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="author_book")
     */
    protected $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }


    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function addBook($book)
    {die("1");//Here is not entering after creating or editing a book!!!!! why????
        $this->books[] = $book;
    }

    public function setBooks($books)
    {die("2");//Here is not entering after creating or editing a book!!!!! why????
        $this->books = $books;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

--------------

namespace Prueba\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="author")
 */
class Author
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */ 
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="authors")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="author_book")
     */
    protected $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }


    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function setBooks($books)
    {
        $this->books = $books;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Book code and also the code where you persist the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you relating the books with the `Author`? Because to relate it you need to do this:

```
$Author->addBook($Book);
```

And you are saying that in addBook:

```
die("1"); //Here is not entering after creating or editing a book! Why?
```

After, when you have done the association between author and book, if you edit `Book`, `Author` will not do anything. The relation is done, change something of a `Book` (except the id) doesn't affect the Author.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/basico/PFC/blob/dev/src/Webgrf/UserBundle/Controller/MemberController.php#L150). I am relating an empty MemberBibtex to a Member. If the form is posted with data I will save it with the persist and the flush. But first, I added it to the Member.